# How to skip dates in Python using checkboxes

Tags: python, checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes each representing a date such as:

```
Week 1: 01/01/2019  [  ] - checkbox 1
Week 2: 08/01/2019  [  ] - checkbox 2
Week 3: 15/01/2019  [  ] - checkbox 3
Week 4: 22/01/2019  [  ] - checkbox 4
Week To Pay 29/01/2019
```

I have tried the following code

```
W1 = W1 = timedelta(days=7)
week_one_raw = "01/01/2019"
week_one_raw = datetime.strptime(FIXED_WEEK_1, '%d/%m/%Y')
week_one_refined = week_one_raw
week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W1
week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_1 == 1:
    week_one_refined = week_one_raw + W1
    week_two_refined = week_one_refined + W1
    week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
    week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_1 == 0:
    week_one_refined = week_one_raw
    week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W1
    week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
    week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_2 == 1:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined + W1
    week_two_refined = week_two_refined + W1
    week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
    week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_2 == 0:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined
    week_two_refined = week_two_refined
    week_three_refined = week_three_refined
    week_four_refined = week_four_refined
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1
```

- The output is correct if Box 1 and 2 are equal to zero
- The output is correct if Box 1 and 2 are equal to one
- The output is correct if Box 1 equals one and Box two equals zero
- The output is incorrect if Box 1 equals zero and Box 2 equals one as it skips a week_one_refined returns a week ahead of what it should do.

Comment: This works when Box 1 and Box 2 = 0
This works when Box 1 = 1 and Box 2 = 1
This works when Box 1 and 2 both = 1
but does not work when Box 1 = 0  and Box 2 = 1

Comment: Can you show in your code how you set the value of BOX_1 and BOX_2, how you print the output, what is the output you're having now and what output you expected?

Comment: Thanks for your help...it was a simple error that's been driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

```
if BOX_2 == 1:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined
```

error in code.

```
#the full code that works


import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

FIXED_WEEK_1 = "15/04/2019" 


W1 = timedelta(days=7)
W2 = timedelta(days=14)
W3 = timedelta(days=21)
W4 = timedelta(days=28)
W5 = timedelta(days=35)

BOX_1 = 0
BOX_2 = 0
BOX_3 = 0
BOX_4 = 0

week_one_raw = datetime.strptime(FIXED_WEEK_1, '%d/%m/%Y')
week_one_refined = week_one_raw
week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W1
week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_1 == 1:
    week_one_refined = week_one_raw + W1
    week_two_refined = week_one_refined + W1
    week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
    week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_1 == 0:
    week_one_refined = week_one_raw
    week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W1
    week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
    week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_2 == 1:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined
    week_two_refined = week_two_refined + W1
    week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
    week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_2 == 0:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined
    week_two_refined = week_two_refined
    week_three_refined = week_three_refined
    week_four_refined = week_four_refined
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_3 == 1:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined
    week_two_refined = week_two_refined
    week_three_refined = week_three_refined +W1
    week_four_refined = week_four_refined + W1
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_3 == 0:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined
    week_two_refined = week_two_refined
    week_three_refined = week_three_refined
    week_four_refined = week_four_refined
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_4 == 1:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined
    week_two_refined = week_two_refined
    week_three_refined = week_three_refined
    week_four_refined = week_four_refined +W1
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined +W1

if BOX_4 == 0:
    week_one_refined = week_one_refined
    week_two_refined = week_two_refined
    week_three_refined = week_three_refined
    week_four_refined = week_four_refined
    week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

print (week_one_refined)
print (week_two_refined)
print (week_three_refined)
print (week_four_refined)
print (week_to_pay_refined)
```

Comment: Damn it...it works fine unless you have two boxes checked in a row...it wont skip two weeks ahead

Answer (score 0):

The answer actually seemed far more complicated and yet simple in practice.

Following a flow chart took me through every possible combination of check boxes needing to be turned on. Ending up looking like a reversed tournament. In the end it took nested for loops to make it function.

For those that are interested see the code below:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

FIXED_WEEK_1 = "16/04/2019" 


W1 = timedelta(days=7)
W2 = timedelta(days=14)
W3 = timedelta(days=21)
W4 = timedelta(days=28)
W5 = timedelta(days=35)
W6 = timedelta(days=42)
W7 = timedelta(days=49)
W8 = timedelta(days=56)

BOX_1 = 1
BOX_2 = 0
BOX_3 = 1
BOX_4 = 1

week_one_raw = datetime.strptime(FIXED_WEEK_1, '%d/%m/%Y')
week_one_refined = week_one_raw
week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W1
week_three_refined = week_two_refined + W1
week_four_refined = week_three_refined + W1
week_to_pay_refined = week_four_refined + W1

if BOX_1 == 0:
    week_one_refined = week_one_raw
    if BOX_2 == 0:
        week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W1
        if BOX_3 == 0:
            week_three_refined = week_one_raw + W2
            if BOX_4 == 0:
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw + W3
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw + W4
            if BOX_4 == 1:
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W5
        if BOX_3 == 1:
            week_three_refined = week_one_raw + W3
            if BOX_4 == 0:
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W3
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W5
            if BOX_4 == 1:
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W5
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W6

    if BOX_2 == 1:
        week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W2
        if BOX_3 == 0:
            week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W2
            if BOX_4 == 0:
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W2
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W3
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W5
            if BOX_4 == 1:
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W3
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W6
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W7
        if BOX_3 == 1:
            week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W3
            if BOX_4 == 0:
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W3
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W5
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W6
            if BOX_4 == 1:
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W4
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W5
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W6
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W7



if BOX_1 == 1:
    week_one_refined = week_one_raw + W1
    if BOX_2 == 0:
        week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W1
        if BOX_3 == 0:
            week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W1
            if BOX_4 ==0:
                week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W1
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W2
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W3
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W5
            if BOX_4 ==1:
                week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W1
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W2
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W3
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W5
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W6
        if BOX_3 ==1:
            week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W1
            if BOX_4 == 0:
                week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W1
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W2
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W5
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W6
            if BOX_4 == 1:
                week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W1
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W2
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W5
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W6
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W7

    if BOX_2 == 1:
        week_one_refined = week_one_raw + W2
        if BOX_3 == 0:
            if BOX_4 ==0:
                week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W2
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W3
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W5
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W6
            if BOX_4 ==1:
                week_one_refined = week_one_raw +W2
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw +W3
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw +W4
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw +W6
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw +W7
        if BOX_3 ==1:
            if BOX_4 ==0:
                week_one_refined = week_one_raw + W3
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W4
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw + W5
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw + W6
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw + W7
            if BOX_4 ==1:
                week_one_refined = week_one_raw + W4
                week_two_refined = week_one_raw + W5
                week_three_refined = week_one_raw + W6
                week_four_refined = week_one_raw + W7
                week_to_pay_refined = week_one_raw + W8
```

Apologies for some inconsistencies within the loops...as in duplication of values. It took me a while to figure out the right method.